# DataTables not processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTables server side with the following codes:

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": "http://clashdata.tk/clans/load",

        "aoColumns": [
            { "data": null },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "playercount" },
            { "data": "warswon" },
            { "data": "warslost" },
            { "data": "warstied" },
            { "data": "level"},
            { "data": "exp"},
            { "data": "location"},
            { "data": "warwinpercent"}
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="/clans/' + aData[1] + '">' + aData[3] + '</a>');
                return nRow;
            },
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                var index = iDisplayIndex + 1;
                $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index);
                return nRow;
            }
        });

        $('#table').dataTable().columnFilter({
            sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
            aoColumns: [null, { type: "text" }, null, null, null, null, null, null, { type: "text" }, null]
        });

    });
```

The table loads on first load but if I try and visit a page in the table, order by column or search etc then it just gets stuck on the Processing bit.

I am sure the problem isn't on the server side because if I visit the server side URL manually it returns the correct results.

One thing I noticed through the console while debugging is that the URL the Ajax script is calling is different than it is for the first
Load.

First load:

```
load?parameters
```

When I try A jquery command or something:

```
clan?parameters
```

How come this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Vague explanations. Impossible to understand.

Comment: Explain what's vague then @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: I've added an explanation after the script code.

Comment: the mode that you requested `clan?parameters`. It's not clarified

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude that's the URL the Ajax call uses when for datatables.

Comment: I know, but is not in the code. We can't see the problem, the code is incomplete. Please, read this and edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You need to create an example that reproduces the issue, and if you attach a fiddle is better and good.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude exactly! It's not in the code when it should be sending the request to /clans/load it is sending it to /clans. That's what I can't figure out so there must be something in the Script or I have the wrong idea about how it works.

Comment: Maybe you need to control this line `$('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="/clans/' + aData[1] + '">'` . Maybe you need to put `/clans/load/` because I don't know how `aData` array returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on DataTables 1.10 and the ColumnFilter plugin doesn't work with it. Upon removing it everything worked fine.